# PHP Variable passed to each() is not an array

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a class function below that caches a users information, what the error im getting is below

```
Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\base\classes\class.user.php on line 67
```

And the function is below.

```
public function cacheUserInfo() {
        if (!$this->loggedIn())
            return;

        global $autoLoader;
        $userQuery = $autoLoader->getLibrary('database')->query("SELECT motto,look,rank,last_login,block_newfriends FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '" . $_SESSION['user']['id']. "'");

        $userRow = mysqli_fetch_array($userQuery);

        while (list($var, $val) = each($userRow)) {
            $_SESSION['user'][$var] = $val;
        }
    }
```

The query function on database library is just the ->query($sql) function for a MySQLi connection.

It was working one second now its not...
 Why am I getting this error?

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` returns either an array or null, so if it isn't an array, then your query didn't return any results.

Comment: I don't see any syntax errors in your query, so I think the most likely explanation is that `$_SESSION['user']['id']` is not set to something that has a matching id in the `users` table.

Comment: If you are unsure if the query returns anything, try `while ($userRow = mysqli_fetch_array($userQuery)) { /* ... */ }` instead of using `each()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use

```
foreach($userRow as $key => $value)
```

It looks like your query might be returning null. If that's the case, maybe you should check if it is null first.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need neither each nor foreach here.

All the code you need is just

```
$_SESSION['user'] =mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery);
```